# What Causes Files to Not be Displayed in File Manager Which Exist

Tags: filemanager

I have a directory which when navigating in file manager shows only about 5 out of 15 of the files (text documents which I have created) which are there. When I navigate to the directory using Atom, I can see the files.

I can open the directory in Atom using "Show in File Manager," but it still does not show in File Manager (so I'm 100% sure it is the same directory).

Comment: Do any of the filenames begin with a period, or other special character?

Answer (score 0):

The files might probably be hidden files,meaning the file name is preceded by "." If that's the case you can display them by pressing  `ctrl + h`